# Некоректный запуск программы (плавающая ошибка)

Tags: autoit

Не могу понять почему Авто ит открывает "странное" окно, при этом раз через раз . Это окно полностью пустое и из за него не получается реализовать исполняющую логику.
Почему так ?? Как это исправить ??

Вот код :

```
;найти программу если запущенна то раскрутить
$hWnd = WinWait("[CLASS:SunAwtFrame]", "", 15)

; свернуть все окна
WinMinimizeAll ( )

If Not $hWnd Then
    ;если программа не запущенна то, запустить
    MsgBox(4096, 'Сообщение', 'Окно не найдено, завершаем работу скрипта')

    ;$hWnd4 =ControlClick($hWnd, "", "[CLASS:SysListView32]", "Left", 1,35, 643)
    ;If Not $hWnd4 Then
    ;   MsgBox(4096, 'Сообщение', 'Строчка не отработала, ControlClick, завершаем работу скрипта')
    ;   Exit
    ;EndIf

    Exit
EndIf
;  развернуть,   восстановить окно.
WinSetState($hWnd, "", @SW_MAXIMIZE)


;MsgBox(4096, 'Сообщение', 'Прошли')
Sleep(500)
;осн позиции 
$Poz_y_g = 500
$Poz_x_g = 250

$Poz_x_t = 50
$Poz_y_t = 200

For $variable = 10 To 1 Step -1
MouseClickDrag("left", 1592, 180, $Poz_y_g, ($Poz_x_g + $Poz_x_t))
$Poz_x_g = $Poz_x_g + $Poz_x_t
Sleep(100)
Next
; возвращаем базовые значения
$Poz_x_g = 250
$Poz_y_g = ($Poz_y_g + $Poz_y_t)

For $variable = 10 To 1 Step -1
MouseClickDrag("left", 1592, 180, $Poz_y_g, ($Poz_x_g + $Poz_x_t))
$Poz_x_g = $Poz_x_g + $Poz_x_t
Sleep(100)
Next
```

Вот запущенные процессы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
ВОт то что мне открывает
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

По сути проблему обошёл воспользовавшись функцией `WinGetHandle()`

Вот код :

```
; свернуть все окна
WinMinimizeAll ( )

$hWnd1  =   WinGetHandle("[CLASS:SunAwtFrame]")
If Not $hWnd1 Then
    MsgBox(4096, 'Сообщение', 'Строчка окна не найдена,WinGetHandle, завершаем работу скрипта')
    Exit
EndIf

;  развернуть,   восстановить окно.
WinSetState($hWnd1, "", @SW_MAXIMIZE)
```